# Replicating table without the dataset

Tags: r, regression

I am supposed to replicate a table in r. the table summarizes OLS regressors which are a result of the analysis on one dataset. I do not have the dataset but am supposed to replicate the table. this table is going to be used in a project when the survey phase is completed.

Comment: can you explain more clearly what information you are expected to recover and what information you have?

Comment: It is not clear what you're asking for

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you just want to build a table in R, rather than reproduce the OLS results based on some other information like the mean and variability of the data.

For each column you can build a list, or vector, using the `c` function:

```
regressors <- c("sunshine","rainfall","wind")
r2 <- c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3)
```

I've invented some data here, but you would fill the numbers/words in based on the table you're trying to replicate.

You can then build these into a table using the `data.frame` function, where you specify the names of the columns, and then point to the previously built lists:

```
table <- data.frame(regressors = regressors,
                    r2 = r2)
```

Or, you can do it all in one go, like this:

```
table <- data.frame(regressors = c("sunshine","rainfall","wind"),
                    r2 = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3))
```

Alternatively, you could just type out the table into a program like Excel, save the worksheet as a csv file, then read it into R using `read.csv`:

```
table <- read.csv("path_to_your_csv_file.csv")
```